# How can I create one local library to use with AWS Lambda (handling with "cannot import name ' _imaging'" error from PIL library)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use the Pillow Image in my project, passing it as a local library to my AWS Lambda Function use.

The files are located like this:

> Backend(folder with the lambda_handler code)
>
> Libraries(folder with some folders to store some libraries)
>
> PIL(folder with the files inside Libraries)

My lambda_handler code is importing Image like this:

```
from Libraries.PIL import Image
```

The only time that I use Image is to open one Image as an argument to one function.

When I upload and test the Lambda Function, I am receiving the following error:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'Backend/lambda_function': cannot import name '_imaging' from 'Libraries.PIL' (/var/task/Libraries/PIL/__init__.py)",
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

I already uninstall all  Pillow versions and tried using only one version, the most recent version (7.2.0), and some old versions (6.0.0 and 5.0.0).

I am using Python 3.7

Note: Running the program locally everything works ok, but when I run it in AWS Lambda the I receive the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to use Pillow, which also could solve your issue, is through [Lambda layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html).

A popular repository with such layers (including pillow) is [keithrozario /
Klayers](https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers) on github. To use it, you would locate ARN of the **layer based on your region**. The list of the ARNs for python 3.7 is [here](https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers/tree/master/deployments/python3.7/arns).

For example, for `us-east-1` the layer added would be:

[image]

And in your function you would use it as follow e.g.:

```
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcin for recommending me to use Lambda_Layers, it will help me a lot, but I am still having the same error. I uploaded the libraries to one layer that I created and it is working very well, but when I run the code the error appears "cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/__init__.py)". I opened the __init__.py file but there has no one reference to _imaging. I am confused now

Comment: @JancerLima Hi. I'm not sure how you could upload any code to the layer? Which layer? Your custom one? You just link the pillow layer using its arn as on the screenshot. You can't modify it content.

Comment: It works, THANK YOU SO MUCH. YOU SAVED MY PROJECT. I had uploaded one Library that I had installed using `pip3 install Pillow`, but using the layers that you recommended to me it works. Thanks again, you are a god.